# Rename/remove samsung-galaxy-gear tag

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

In my opinion [samsung-galaxy-gear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/samsung-galaxy-gear) tag is invalid.

First of all there's no such device as "Galaxy Gear". The Gear devices with Tizen OS are as follows:

- Gear
- Gear 2
- Gear 2 Neo
- Gear Fit

And with Android Wear:

- Gear Live

People are using this tag in questions regarding both Android and Tizen based watches. This tag is ambiguous because it contains unrelated questions.

Comment: The original Samsung Gear watch was named [Samsung Galaxy Gear](http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/wearable-tech/SM-V7000ZKAXAR), so it'd seem to be appropriate. See also http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung-galaxy-gear

Comment: @AlE. You're right because it was released with Android. Galaxy is a prefix for all Android products from Samsung. But one day the OS has been changed to Tizen and if you look at Samsung site there's no more Galaxy prefix: https://www.samsung.com/global/microsite/gear/index.html Still all the questions are about Gear 2 or Gear Live so I think this tag should be removed/renamed.